# When does Azure AD generate a new access token in implicit grant flow, (no refresh token)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

1. Say we have a valid access token and again request for an access token, does Azure give a new token or return the same valid token.
2. Say we have a  valid token for 1hr and it is about to expire in 1 min, and  if we request for a new token , does AD generate a new token ?

   Can we configure these settings in Azure AD, say for every token request it should generate a new token even the existing token is valid or can we configure that if  a new token is requested which is about to expire in a minute generate a new token

Comment: Use a library like MSAL and you don’t need to worry about these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all your three questions is:

Azure AD generates a new access token every time it is asked for an access token.

Comment: Just to add to this: with implicit grant you get a new token every time _as long as the Azure AD session for the user is active_. If the user no longer has an active session (maybe they logged out of another app that logged them out of AAD), you will get an error instead.

Comment: you are mos probably talking about the acquiretokensilent, which is based on the websso cookie with the aurhorize endpoint. but msal handles this event ange you control how to go on - promt the use to sign in again or die. The question however was whethe Azure AD reissues same access token or generates a new one with every request... ;)